# How do I respond to this?

Tags: questions

I asked someone how their day is going. They responded "Hello and it's going lol" how do i respond to that? or was that a way of saying dont bother me?

Comment: Respond however you want -- what they said makes no sense.

Comment: no really sure where to go from there haha xD

Comment: I was serious..

Comment: I think its simply a case of the giggles. The respondent's reply (for reasons that remain mysterious) devolved into  ... well, a fit of laughter. It happens. :- ))

Answer (score 1):

The responder may have actually meant "It's going! (LOL)"

In this case it would be a friendly, humorous reply that is non-specific, except that it hints of "If you only knew!  But, I'm handling it, things are cool."